# Unsubscribe from observable before interval fired again

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm developing an angular 5 application where I have an Observable like this one:

```typescript
Observable.interval(10000)
    .takeWhile(() => !this.zeServerIsOnline)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        this.systemService.isServerOnline().subscribe(data => {
            if(data.success) {
                this.zeServerIsOnline = true;
                this.serverPolledForState = false;
                if(this.bookingsInStorage > 0) {
                    this.allBookingsSubmitted = false;
                    this.sendSavedBookingsToServer();
                }
            }
        }, error => this.isServerOnlineFailed(error));
    });
```

i first thought, that the observable gets directly unsubscribed, when my Boolean `this.zeServerIsOnline` gets true but it gets unsubscribed, when again 10 seconds are over and the observable recognizes the state of my Boolean (`this.zeServerIsOnline`) is true than.

So if i now recognize, that my server is online again (`this.zeServerIsOnline = true`), i'm starting transmitting data (and i thought that this is the place, when the observable is unsubscribed) But now, when the server goes offline again while i'm transmitting data and 10 seconds are not over my Observable triggers again because it didn't recognize the switch from `false` to `true` to `false`.

Only when my server is online longer than 10 seconds, my observable gets unsubscribed. So it must have sth. to do with the interval but how do i directly unsubscribe, when `this.zeServerIsOnline` gets true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable type of `ISubscription`

```typescript
subscription: ISubscription;
```

Let's think you need to unsubscribe `this.systemService.isServerOnline()`. You could do it like:

```typescript
this.subscription = this.systemService.isServerOnline().subscribe(data => {
            if(data.success) {
                this.zeServerIsOnline = true;
                this.serverPolledForState = false;
                if(this.bookingsInStorage > 0) {
                    this.allBookingsSubmitted = false;
                    this.sendSavedBookingsToServer();
                }
            }
        }, error => this.isServerOnlineFailed(error));
```

Or if you need to unsubscribe `Observable.interval(10000)` you could do it like:

```typescript
this.subscription = Observable.interval(10000)
      .takeWhile(() => !this.zeServerIsOnline)
      .subscribe(i => {
        this.systemService.isServerOnline().subscribe(data => {
          if (data.success) {
            this.zeServerIsOnline = true;
            this.serverPolledForState = false;
            if (this.bookingsInStorage > 0) {
              this.allBookingsSubmitted = false;
              this.sendSavedBookingsToServer();
            }
          }
        }, error => this.isServerOnlineFailed(error));
      });
```

And now you could directly unsubscribe it:

```typescript
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

You can directly unsubscribe what ever subscription in this way.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer coder, i'm new to rxjs so who do i trigger a 10 second interval than on that subscription? So i need to call it every 10 seconds and unsubscribe than inside my `this.sendSavedBookingsToServer()` function.

Comment: you could get the `interval(10000)` subscription into that `this.subscription` variable and unsubscribe it inside `this.sendSavedBookingsToServer()` function using `this.subscription.unsubscribe();`

Comment: @Sithys Glad to hear it!